# MySql LIKE '%str%' returns wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have a table where there are multiple columns and one is a string that holds the location of the user eg: 'Toronto,Ontario,Canada' along with the id, user name, email and other information.

A row is returned and displayed in a table and I can input a search string for any one of the columns. If no string is input for a given column then it doesn't filtre on that column.

The suggestion of using parenthesis doesn't help since when only the location is being searched the OR statement isn't even being added. So why am I getting random wrong results. Just did a search for England and had Dallas Texas returned and many others that made no sense at all.

```
            $sql="SELECT 
                u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.created,
                up.user_name, up.location_label
                FROM users u
                    JOIN profile up ON up.user_id=u.id
                WHERE ";

                $sql.=!empty($post['id'])?"u.id={$post['id']} AND ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['name'])?"u.firstname LIKE '%{$post['name']}%' OR ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['name'])?"u.lastname LIKE '%{$post['name']}%' AND ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['email'])?"u.email LIKE '%{$post['email']}%' AND ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['created'])?"u.created LIKE '%{$post['created']}%' AND ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['userName'])?"up.user_name LIKE '%{$post['userName']}%' AND ":"";
                $sql.=!empty($post['location'])?"up.location_label LIKE '%{$post['location']}%' AND ":"";

                $sql=rtrim($sql,"WHERE ");
                $sql=rtrim($sql,"AND ");

                $sql.=" ORDER BY u.id DESC ";
                $sql.=" LIMIT {$post['lastIndex']}, {$post['loadNum']} ";
```

What I am finding is if I search for a specific location string eg: 'Ontario' I get lots of results for 'Ontario' but I will also get results that don't have 'Ontario' in the string or even close to it. What would be happening here to cause that. It will return a bunch of correct rows, then some completely wrong ones and then more correct ones again.

Returned Rows eg:

```
Brampton,Ontario,Canada
Toronto,Ontario,Canada
,Illinois,United States
Tecumseh,Ontario,Canada
Dayton,Ohio,United States
Keller,Texas,United States
Philadelphia,Pennsylvania,United States
Mississauga,Ontario,Canada  
Toronto,Ontario,Canada
```

What is causing this mess?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: You should really look up on sanitation.

Comment: Learn about operator precedence,you need parentheses since you have an OR in there.

Comment: You should put firstname, lastname part into paranthesis because there is an OR. 
(firstname like ... OR lastname like ...)

Comment: @Hallur I clean my bathrooms and take out the garbage every week, but thanks for the suggestion.

Mihai and Sherif, Makes sense now that I see it. Thanks for a useful answer.

Comment: @PaulNeale thanks for the laugh :D

Comment: Still doesn't work with paranthesis. Any other ideas?

Comment: Edit your question with your last query,echo out the $sql.

Comment: Trying to narrow it down and will post when I have a better idea of what is happening.